# What is the at ("@") operator in Pharo?

Tags: pharo

I've looked online for a meaning of the `@` operator in Pharo, but couldn't find anything.

What's the meaning of the Pharo `@` operator? For instance, why does `25@50` get evaluated as: `"(25@50)"`?

Comment: @ is not an operator, it’s a message just like almost everything. The basis of Smalltalk is messages sent to objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Smalltalk, the `@` symbol is used to create instances of the class `Point`. An instance of such a class has two ivars `x` and `y`. You can create a `Point` using the `x:y:` message, like this

```
  Point x: 3 y: 4.
```

However, it is less verbose to use the message `@` like this

```
  3 @ 4
```

to create the same thing.

Note that while `x:y:` is a message you send to the class `Point`, the message `@ 4` is sent to the integer `3`. In other words, the former is a class message, the latter an instance message.

Note that, since many people write `3@4` instead of `3 @ 4`, this has the risk of creating a surprising side effect. In fact

```
  3@-4
```

should be (in principle) the `Point` with coordinates `3` and `-4`. However, the Smalltalk syntax is different and will parse it as the message with selector `@-` and argument `4` sent to the receiver `3`. This is why some dialects make an exception so that the message is interpreted as `3 @ -4`, which can be achieved by implementing the method `@-` in `Number` or by tweaking the parser.

Answer (score 1):

In Pharo it is a method defined in the Number class

```
@ y 
"Primitive. Answer a Point whose x value is the receiver and whose y 
value is the argument. Optional. No Lookup. See Object documentation 
whatIsAPrimitive."

<primitive: 18>
^Point x: self y: y
```